# Detect Comma/Enter key press

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are some comma separated values in an input field. I want to alert a message when I am pressing the COMMA(`,`) or ENTER key. I have given the code that I used for this, but didn't work. Is there anything inefficient about this?

```
$(document).on("keyup", '.tagsinput', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13 || e.which == 44) {
        alert('comma added');
    }
});
```

Comment: is the tag input being added dynamically?

Comment: `COMMA` and `ENTER` at the same time?

Comment: @Tushar that's an `OR`, not an `AND`.

Comment: @AlexMcMillan `I want to alert a message when I am pressing the comma and enter key`

Comment: @Tushar Don't pick on people because of their English.  It's pretty clear what was meant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `keycode` (`which` in jQuery) for a comma is `188`

There is a brilliant tool for this [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

Comment: please look at the code given below,in this i used a tag input field for entering sub locations coming under a specific location.i want to avoid the duplicate entry while typing the sub location names.how can i check(when i press enter/comma and also on onclick event) this with jquery? <label>Sub Location Names</label> <input name="tagsinput" class="tagsinput" data-maxwidth="200" id="ptag" value="" />

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).on("keyup", '.tagsinput', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 188) { // KeyCode For comma is 188
        alert('comma added');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/3yLwgwhb/

Comment: @Ilyaskarim Check http://keycode.info/ and https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

Answer (score 3):

Try using `keypress` instead of `keyup`:

```js
$(function() { //<-- you are missing this
  $(document).on("keypress", '.tagsinput', function(e) { //<-- note, its keypress
    console.log('key pressed ', e.which);
    if (e.which == 13 || e.which == 44) {
      return false; //<-- prevent
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' class='tagsinput' />
<input type='text' class='tagsinput' />
```

Comment: @Tushar, kindly run my script and have a look at the browser console

Answer (score 3):

## Use `event.key` and modern JS!

*No number codes* anymore. You can check for <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>,</kbd> key directly.

```
const input = document.getElementById("inputId");
input.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter" || event.key === ",") {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[Supported Browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't listen for keyup, better way is to listen for keypress:

```
$('.tagsinput').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13 || e.which == 44) {
        alert('comma added');
    }
});
```

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/doe7qk6r/

Comment: There are plenty of reasons why `keyup` could have been chosen over `keypress`.. neither is "better" without a full use-case, which OP has not provided.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tagsinput").bind('keypress', function(e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if(code == 44) { // comma key code is 44
            str= $('#tagsinput').val();
            str.substring(0, str.length - 2);
            arr = str.split(",");
            key = arr[arr.length-1];
            arr.splice(arr.length-1, 1);
            if(arr.indexOf( key )!=-1){
                alert("Duplicate detected : "+key);
                //uncomment the next line to remove the duplicated word just after it detects !
                //$('#tagsinput').val(arr);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Sub Location Names</label> 
<input name="tagsinput" id="tagsinput" class="tagsinput" data-maxwidth="200" id="ptag" value="" />
```

hope this will work for you :)

Comment: this tag input field is used for entering sub locations coming under a specific location.i want to avoid the duplicate entry while typing the sub location name.how can i check(when i press enter/comma  and onclick) this with jquery?


<label>Sub Location Names</label>
 <input name="tagsinput" class="tagsinput" data-maxwidth="200" id="ptag" value="" />`